# Swift3 handle alertviewcontroller ok and cancel button

Tags: swift3, xcode8

Code:

```
let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "StopRequest", message: msg, preferredStyle: .alert)

        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel) { (action:UIAlertAction!) in
        }
        alertController.addAction(cancelAction)

        let OKAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default) { (action:UIAlertAction!) in
        }
        alertController.addAction(OKAction)

        self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion:nil)
```

I create a UIAlertViewController in swift3.
Alertview is working fine.Please help me on how to handle ok and cancel events.If we have more than one alert how to differentiate them?.thanks in advance

Comment: Eh? `How to handle` — put code in `UIAlertAction` closure. `If we have more than one alert how to differentiate them?` — add different actions to different alerts, unless different alerts must perform same action.

Comment: got. it..thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

```
 let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Wrong Email Or Password", message: "Please Check Your Email or Password", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)


                    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default)
                    {
                        _ in  // add actions here

                        }
                    )
                    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: please add some information why and how this solves the problem in OP.